# How to solve the division between variables trouble on vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

I'm working with a function generator project based on the DDS method (Direct Digital Synthesis) to implement in a Basys 2, But when I run the Synthesize I get an

```
ERROR ("ERROR:Xst:769 - "C:/Users/dell6410/Desktop/DDS    VHDL/DDS_VHDL/triangularwave.vhd"
line 55: Operator <DIVIDE> must have constant operands or first operand must be power of 2")`
```

The error is caused by a division between two variable integers and this does not allow me to generate the programming file. Does someone know a solution?

```
n :in integer; 

variable count:integer:=0;

op <= count*255 / n;
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code? I tried the same after setting a `signal count` and it compiles perfectly in `ghdl`. I suppose it's something specific to Xilinx `Xst`

Comment: As a general rule, avoid using division. There is almost always a different way of doing whatever it is you are trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

Copying from the Xilinx support [document](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_4/xst_v6s6.pdf) (page 183), a divider can be implemented only when,

> The divisor is constant and a power of 2.

Clearly, your `n` is not a constant. In such divisions, it's difficult for hardware to determine the resule efficiently in one cycle.

In a general purpose divider, it's better you implement the division as a process subtracting the number every clock instance.

```
signal quotient: integer := 0;
signal remainder: integer := 0;
signal division_complete: std_logic := '0';
-- Begin architecture
process(clk, dividend, divisor, quotient, remainder)
  variable n_quotient: integer := 0;
  variable n_remainder: integer := 0;
  variable n_division_complete: std_logic := '0';
begin
  n_quotient := quotient;
  n_remainder := remainder;
  n_division_complete := '0';
  if (dividend < divisor) then
    -- End of division
    n_division_complete := '1';
  elif (division_complete = '1') then
    -- Start of next division
    n_division_complete := '1';
    n_quotient := 0;
  else
    -- Division in progress
    n_quotient := n_quotient + 1;
    n_remainder := dividend - divisor;
  end if;
  if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
    quotient <= n_quotient;
    remainder <= n_remainder;
    division_complete <= n_division_complete;
  end if;
end process;
```

In case a synchronous solution as above is not feasible, you will need to constraint your inputs to the Xilinx conditions as specified above. In case your division is a simple divide by a power of 2, you could use the `>>` (right shift) operator.